# How is the default usage of pip2 in Manjaro?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pip, manjaro

I'm a bit confused about the default usage of pip2 in Linux Manjaro.

Python2 and Python3 are installed by default as well as pip (for python3).

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4

$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.16

$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

But pip2 fails

```
$ pip2 --version
bash: pip2: command not found
```

I'm sure i can install pip2 via pacman, but whats the initial intention to roll out python2 without a depending pip2 version?

Or did i simply missing something here?